# R: "Protecting" Code Against " arguments imply differing number of rows"

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

Patient_ID = 1:5000
gender <- c("Male","Female")
gender <- sample(gender, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.45, 0.55))
Gender <- as.factor(gender)


status <- c("Immigrant","Citizen")
status <- sample(status, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
Status  <- as.factor(status )

Height = rnorm(5000, 150, 10)
Weight = rnorm(5000, 90, 10)
Hospital_Visits = sample.int(20,  5000, replace = TRUE)

################

disease <- c("Yes","No")
disease <- sample(disease, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6))
Disease <- as.factor(disease)

###################
my_data = data.frame(Patient_ID, Gender, Status, Height, Weight, Hospital_Visits, Disease)
```

I am trying to calculate the min/max ranges for the height, weight and hospital_visit variables based on 5 ntiles. I did this with the following code:

```
table_data <- data.frame(
 Groups = paste0("Group ", 1:5),
  Min_Height = tapply(my_data$Height, ntile(my_data$Height, 5), min),
  Max_Height = tapply(my_data$Height, ntile(my_data$Height, 5), max),
  Min_Weight = tapply(my_data$Weight, ntile(my_data$Weight, 5), min),
  Max_Weight = tapply(my_data$Weight, ntile(my_data$Weight, 5), max),
 Min_Visits = tapply(my_data$Hospital_Visits, ntile(my_data$Hospital_Visits, 5), min),
Max_Visits = tapply(my_data$Hospital_Visits, ntile(my_data$Hospital_Visits, 5), max)
)
```

**My Question:** Suppose now I want to repeat the above code - but for some of the variables have 5 ntiles and for some of the variables have 4 ntiles:

```
  table_data <- data.frame(
     Groups = paste0("Group ", 1:5),
      Min_Height = tapply(my_data$Height, ntile(my_data$Height, 5), min),
      Max_Height = tapply(my_data$Height, ntile(my_data$Height, 5), max),
      Min_Weight = tapply(my_data$Weight, ntile(my_data$Weight, 5), min),
      Max_Weight = tapply(my_data$Weight, ntile(my_data$Weight, 5), max),
     Min_Visits = tapply(my_data$Hospital_Visits, ntile(my_data$Hospital_Visits, 4), min),
    Max_Visits = tapply(my_data$Hospital_Visits, ntile(my_data$Hospital_Visits, 4), max)
    )
```

I then get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(Groups = paste0("Group ", 1:5), Min_Height = tapply(my_data$Height,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 4
```

I would have thought that a value of NA would have been inserted on the "Group 5" row for variables where ntile < 5 ... but instead, the entire code does not run now.

In general, is there something I can do to "protect" my R code from such errors? That is, in situations where I have a differing number of ntiles being calculated - can something be done to automatically assign NA values to groups which are not "relevant" for a specific variable?

```
   Groups Min_Height Max_Height Min_Weight Max_Weight Min_Visits Max_Visits
1 Group 1   111.5468   141.4839   56.53098   81.83402          1          5
2 Group 2   141.4965   147.4422   81.85064   87.45406          5          10
3 Group 3   147.4487   152.3924   87.45935   92.72041         10          15
4 Group 4   152.4016   158.5178   92.72941   98.54624         16         20
5 Group 5   158.5187   188.4777   98.55533  121.02420         NA         NA
```

Thanks!

**Note:** Currently I am doing this manually (i.e. create a separate table for ntile = 4 and ntile = 5) and then merging the results - but ideally I would like to perform all ntile calculations within the same code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking yourself "How can I get the answer I want from the data I have?".  I think a better question is "How do I construct my data to get the answer I want easily and robustly?".

The answer to the second question is by pivoting your input data.  For example:

```
my_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    c(Height, Weight, Hospital_Visits), 
    names_to = "Column", 
    values_to = "Value"
  ) 
# A tibble: 15,000 × 6
   Patient_ID Gender Status    Disease Column          Value
        <int> <fct>  <fct>     <fct>   <chr>           <dbl>
 1          1 Female Citizen   No      Height          145. 
 2          1 Female Citizen   No      Weight          114. 
 3          1 Female Citizen   No      Hospital_Visits   1  
 4          2 Male   Immigrant No      Height          161. 
 5          2 Male   Immigrant No      Weight           88.3
 6          2 Male   Immigrant No      Hospital_Visits  18  
 7          3 Female Immigrant Yes     Height          139. 
 8          3 Female Immigrant Yes     Weight           99.3
 9          3 Female Immigrant Yes     Hospital_Visits   6  
10          4 Male   Citizen   No      Height          165. 
# … with 14,990 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Now we can easily calculate a "by-column" ntile by using `group_map`.  (This function applies the function defined by its argument to each of the current groups of a data frame.)

Conventionally, the function takes two arguments, `.x`, which contains the data in the current group, and `.y` which is a single-row tibble that *defines* the current group.

Setting `.keep` to `TRUE` ensures that the group columns remain in `.x`.  By default, they don't. `group_map` returns a list, so I use `bind_rows` to combine the results into a single data frame.

Note that I define the desired number of groups for each column in the original data frame in a vector.

```
nGroups <- c("Height" = 5, "Weight" = 5, "Hospital_Visits" = 4)

my_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    c(Height, Weight, Hospital_Visits), 
    names_to = "Column", 
    values_to = "Value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Column) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      .x %>% mutate(Group = paste0("Group_", ntile(Value, nGroups[.y$Column])))
    },
    .keep = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows() 
# A tibble: 15,000 × 7
   Patient_ID Gender Status    Disease Column Value Group  
        <int> <fct>  <fct>     <fct>   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  
 1          1 Female Citizen   No      Height  145. Group_2
 2          2 Male   Immigrant No      Height  161. Group_5
 3          3 Female Immigrant Yes     Height  139. Group_1
 4          4 Male   Citizen   No      Height  165. Group_5
 5          5 Male   Citizen   Yes     Height  159. Group_5
 6          6 Female Citizen   Yes     Height  153. Group_4
 7          7 Female Citizen   No      Height  156. Group_4
 8          8 Male   Citizen   Yes     Height  152. Group_3
 9          9 Male   Immigrant Yes     Height  146. Group_2
10         10 Female Citizen   No      Height  147. Group_2
# … with 14,990 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Now I can calculate the summaries you want.

```
my_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    c(Height, Weight, Hospital_Visits), 
    names_to = "Column", 
    values_to = "Value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Column) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      .x %>% mutate(Group = paste0("Group_", ntile(Value, nGroups[.y$Column])))
    },
    .keep = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  group_by(Column, Group) %>% 
  summarise(
    Min = min(Value),
    Max = max(Value),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
# A tibble: 14 × 4
   Column          Group     Min   Max
   <chr>           <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Height          Group_1 112.  141. 
 2 Height          Group_2 141.  147. 
 3 Height          Group_3 147.  152. 
 4 Height          Group_4 152.  159. 
 5 Height          Group_5 159.  188. 
 6 Hospital_Visits Group_1   1     5  
 7 Hospital_Visits Group_2   5    10  
 8 Hospital_Visits Group_3  10    15  
 9 Hospital_Visits Group_4  16    20  
10 Weight          Group_1  56.5  81.8
11 Weight          Group_2  81.9  87.5
12 Weight          Group_3  87.5  92.7
13 Weight          Group_4  92.7  98.5
14 Weight          Group_5  98.6 121.
```

Personally, I'd keep the results in this format for further processing - because it's tidy.  But often *presentation* works better in wider rather than long format.  So when ready to present, you can:

```
my_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    c(Height, Weight, Hospital_Visits), 
    names_to = "Column", 
    values_to = "Value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Column) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      .x %>% mutate(Group = paste0("Group_", ntile(Value, nGroups[.y$Column])))
    },
    .keep = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  group_by(Column, Group) %>% 
  summarise(
    Min = min(Value),
    Max = max(Value),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = Group, 
    values_from = c(Min, Max),
    names_from = Column,
    names_glue = '{.value}_{Column}'
  )
# A tibble: 5 × 7
  Group   Min_Height Min_Hospital_Visits Min_Weight Max_Height Max_Hospital_Visits Max_Weight
  <chr>        <dbl>               <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>               <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Group_1       112.                   1       56.5       141.                   5       81.8
2 Group_2       141.                   5       81.9       147.                  10       87.5
3 Group_3       147.                  10       87.5       152.                  15       92.7
4 Group_4       152.                  16       92.7       159.                  20       98.5
5 Group_5       159.                  NA       98.6       188.                  NA      121.
```

This approach is robust against changes in column names and the desired number of groups.  Hence, it "protects" your code as you request.  The only thing you need to check if you have different variables in the future is that you change the value of `nGroups` accordingly.  if you have extra columns in `nGroups`, that's fine.  If you have a column that you want to summarise that doesn't have an entry in `nGroups`, then you'll get an error.  But it's easy to protect yourself against that.  To *really* protect yourself, define `nGroups` at the start of your code and change the initial `pivot_longer` to

```
my_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    names(nGroups), 
    names_to = "Column", 
    values_to = "Value"
  ) ...
```

Comment: @ Limey: Thank you so much for your answer! As you pointed out in the comments - both of you indeed have Great Minds!

Comment: Do you think its possible to directly integrate your logic within this (related) question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76551409/r-merging-a-lookup-table-with-a-data-frame

Comment: Yes.  I think it should be straightforward.  First group your tibble and then take either of the workflows that @DaveArmstrong and I have given you here and apply them to each group of the input tibble in much the same way as I used `group_map` in my answer.

Comment: The absolutely critical thing for an easy workflow is to _keep your data tidy_. By including the summary statistic (and original column name) in the column names in your intermediate data frame, you have an untidy workflow: your column headers contain values.  See the "Tidying messy datasets" section of [this article](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html).

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to pivot the data longer first, calculate the group variable by a call to `ntile()` and then `group_by()` on the variable name and quantile group.  First, we can make the data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)

Patient_ID = 1:5000
gender <- c("Male","Female")
gender <- sample(gender, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.45, 0.55))
Gender <- as.factor(gender)


status <- c("Immigrant","Citizen")
status <- sample(status, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
Status  <- as.factor(status )

Height = rnorm(5000, 150, 10)
Weight = rnorm(5000, 90, 10)
Hospital_Visits = sample.int(20,  5000, replace = TRUE)

################

disease <- c("Yes","No")
disease <- sample(disease, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6))
Disease <- as.factor(disease)

###################
my_data = data.frame(Patient_ID, Gender, Status, Height, Weight, Hospital_Visits, Disease)
```

Below, we actually do the summarizing.

```r
my_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(Height:Hospital_Visits, names_to="vbl", values_to="vals") %>% 
  group_by(vbl) %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when(
    vbl %in% c("Height", "Weight") ~ ntile(vals, 5), 
    vbl %in% c("Hospital_Visits") ~ ntile(vals, 4)), 
    vbl = gsub("Hospital_", "", vbl)) %>% 
  group_by(vbl, group) %>% 
  reframe(min = min(vals), 
          max=max(vals)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "vbl", 
              names_glue = "{vbl}_{.value}",
              values_from = c("min", "max"))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 7
#>   group Height_min Visits_min Weight_min Height_max Visits_max Weight_max
#>   <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1       112.          1       56.5       141.          5       81.8
#> 2     2       141.          5       81.9       147.         10       87.5
#> 3     3       147.         10       87.5       152.         15       92.7
#> 4     4       152.         16       92.7       159.         20       98.5
#> 5     5       159.         NA       98.6       188.         NA      121.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Great minds.... ;=)

Comment: I agree with @Limey - both of you have Great Minds indeed!

Comment: Do you think its possible to integrate the logic you have provided within this (related) question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76551409/r-merging-a-lookup-table-with-a-data-frame