# R: Merging a Lookup Table with a Data Frame

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset on medical characteristics of patients and disease prevalance:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

Patient_ID = 1:5000
gender <- c("Male","Female")
gender <- sample(gender, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.45, 0.55))
Gender <- as.factor(gender)


status <- c("Immigrant","Citizen")
status <- sample(status, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
Status  <- as.factor(status )

Height = rnorm(5000, 150, 10)
Weight = rnorm(5000, 90, 10)
Hospital_Visits = sample.int(20,  5000, replace = TRUE)

################

disease <- c("Yes","No")
disease <- sample(disease, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6))
Disease <- as.factor(disease)

###################
my_data = data.frame(Patient_ID, Gender, Status, Height, Weight, Hospital_Visits, Disease)

  Patient_ID Gender    Status   Height    Weight Hospital_Visits Disease
1          1 Female   Citizen 145.0583 113.70725               1      No
2          2   Male Immigrant 161.2759  88.33188              18      No
3          3 Female Immigrant 138.5305  99.26961               6     Yes
4          4   Male   Citizen 164.8102  84.31848              12      No
5          5   Male   Citizen 159.1619  92.25090              12     Yes
6          6 Female   Citizen 153.3513 101.31986              11     Yes
```

**Based on this dataset, I am trying to calculate the disease proportions within "nested groups"**, i.e.

- First, select all males
- Then, select all male citizens
- Then, out of the set of all male citizens - identify a group of 20% of this set with the smallest heights
- Then, out of the set of all male citizens within the shortest 20% height - further isolate a group of 20% with the smallest weights
- Finally, out of the set of all male citizens within the shortest 20% height and within the shortest 20% height having the 20% smallest weight - further isolate them into a group with the 20% fewest number of hospital visits : This will now be the first group
- Repeat this process for all possible group combinations

**Part 1:** Using the ".add = TRUE" argument within DPLYR, I think I can accomplish this as follows:

```
nested_combinations <- my_data %>%
  group_by(Gender) %>%
  group_by(Status, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(height_group = ntile(Height, 5)) %>%
  group_by(height_group, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(weight_group = ntile(Weight, 5)) %>%
  group_by(weight_group, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(visits_group = ntile(Hospital_Visits, 5)) %>%
  group_by(visits_group, add = TRUE) %>%
  summarize(total_count = n(),
            disease_count = sum(Disease == "Yes"),
            disease_proportion = mean(Disease == "Yes"))

# results 

  Gender Status  height_group weight_group visits_group total_count disease_count disease_proportion
   <fct>  <fct>          <int>        <int>        <int>       <int>         <int>              <dbl>
 1 Female Citizen            1            1            1          16             5              0.312
 2 Female Citizen            1            1            2          16             4              0.25 
 3 Female Citizen            1            1            3          16             7              0.438
 4 Female Citizen            1            1            4          15             4              0.267
 5 Female Citizen            1            1            5          15             8              0.533
 6 Female Citizen            1            2            1          16             5              0.312
 7 Female Citizen            1            2            2          16             4              0.25 
 8 Female Citizen            1            2            3          16             8              0.5  
 9 Female Citizen            1            2            4          15             6              0.4  
10 Female Citizen            1            2            5          15             6              0.4
```

**Part 2:** Next, I created a "Lookup Table" by calculating the "ranges" (i.e. min and max) for each of these groups:

```
table_data <- data.frame(
 Groups = paste0("Group ", 1:5),
  Min_Height = tapply(my_data$Height, ntile(my_data$Height, 5), min),
  Max_Height = tapply(my_data$Height, ntile(my_data$Height, 5), max),
  Min_Weight = tapply(my_data$Weight, ntile(my_data$Weight, 5), min),
  Max_Weight = tapply(my_data$Weight, ntile(my_data$Weight, 5), max),
 Min_Visits = tapply(my_data$Hospital_Visits, ntile(my_data$Hospital_Visits, 5), min),
Max_Visits = tapply(my_data$Hospital_Visits, ntile(my_data$Hospital_Visits, 5), max)
)

# results

   Groups Min_Height Max_Height Min_Weight Max_Weight Min_Visits Max_Visits
1 Group 1   111.5468   141.4839   56.53098   81.83402          1          4
2 Group 2   141.4965   147.4422   81.85064   87.45406          4          8
3 Group 3   147.4487   152.3924   87.45935   92.72041          8         12
4 Group 4   152.4016   158.5178   92.72941   98.54624         12         17
5 Group 5   158.5187   188.4777   98.55533  121.02420         17         20
```

**My Question:** Is there a way I can take these min/max ranges for the different variables from Part 2 and insert them into Part 1 as new columns (e.g. min_height, max_height, min_weight, max_weight, min_visits, max_visits)?

Currently I am doing this with a series of "ifelse" statements but this does not seem very efficient. Can someone please show me a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something along these lines?

```
## example data
d <-
d <- data.frame(gender = gl(2, 10),
           height = 160 + sample(1:40, 40),
           weight = 50 + sample(1:50, 40),
           disease = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 40, replace = TRUE)
           )
```

```
d |>
  group_by(gender) |>
  mutate(low_height = height < quantile(height, .2)) |>
  group_by(gender, low_height) |>
  mutate(low_weight = weight < quantile(weight, .2)) |>
  group_by(gender, low_height, low_weight) |>
  summarise(across(c(height, weight),
                   ## list custom stats here:
                   list(min = \(xs) min(xs, na.rm = TRUE),
                        max = \(xs) max(xs, na.rm = TRUE)
                        ),
                   .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"
                   ),
            prop_disease = sum(disease)/n(),
            ## etc.
)
```

```
# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   gender, low_height [4]
  gender low_height low_weight height_min height_max weight_min weight_max
  <fct>  <lgl>      <lgl>           <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 1      FALSE      FALSE             172        199         67        100
2 1      FALSE      TRUE              173        190         52         65
3 1      TRUE       FALSE             161        169         74         94
4 1      TRUE       TRUE              165        165         61         61
5 2      FALSE      FALSE             168        200         56         96
6 2      FALSE      TRUE              170        192         51         54
7 2      TRUE       FALSE             164        167         68         93
8 2      TRUE       TRUE              163        163         55         55
# i 1 more variable: prop_disease <dbl>
```

Comment: @ I_O thank you so much for your answer! Can this code be adapted for the min and max of all variables being binned? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ I_O; Thank you so much! Just to clarify : the low_height, low_weight columns are intermediate steps that can be removed from the final result?

Comment: Once they've been generated you can of course keep or drop them like any dataframe's columns. They are created in the `summarise` step and that's that (no live formula behind the values like in spreadsheet software).

Comment: I have a question about your code  - I posted it in a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76552054/r-how-to-prevent-overlapping-ranges-within-nested-summary-groups can you please take a look if you have time? Thanks!